# Access 2010, stop form from updating table

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010

I have been having some trouble with this and it seems to be the opposite of what other people want to do. I have a list of computers that I am maintaining in Access 2010. I want to create a form that I could enter the user's name and have a sub-table show me what computers they have. Ideally, I want to create a text box that would do a search. So far, I am too new to Access to figure out how to do that (I tried with an unbound text box, but couldnt get them to link properly).
Instead, I have created a drop down menu with a list of all the users. I can select a user and a sub-table will bring up the entry with their computer's information in it (service tag, name, type, etc.). 
The problem is that while changing the drop down menu choices to other users, the table is being changed so that it now says the owner of a computer is someone else. For example, I search for Ted. It will bring up his computer. Then I will search for fred's computer. The results will be Ted's computer and Fred's computer. When I go into the actual table to look at Fred's and Ted's computers, they are now both set to being Fred's computers.
Is there a better way to do this (ie using a search text box) and/or to block edits to the table completely from the form?

Comment: The easiest way to solve this is to find a good tutorial on search forms, and follow it.  https://www.google.com/search?q=build+search+form+in+msaccess+tutorial.  This looks like a good one: http://www.599cd.com/VideoPlayer/?FN=http://www.amicron2.com/videos/tips/access/multi-field-search.wmv&W=645&H=430

Comment: I personally like using a list box and text box with a search button.  Enter the text, click search, use VBA to create a SQL string against a recordset, and then use `that_list_box.rowsource = SQL_string` to populate the listbox.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will give these both a try and see it comes out.

Comment: That video was a great step in the right direction. Thanks guys!